# Finding maximum value

Tags: c

Ten million elements are entered into an array (no memory constraints). As we know, while entering the elements we can update the max out of entered values by a check whenever we enter a value.

But imagine if the position of max value is somewhere around 9 million

If I remove 2 million elements in positions 8 to 10 million
without doing any more comparisons, we should have the next maximum value.
Will that mean while entering the data we should have a plan to organize the data in some way to get the max value out of the remaining data?

Deleting and inserting will keep on happening, but we should have the new/residual maximum value updated in less time with a smaller number of steps. (Using multiple stacks might help.)

Comment: Please do not use local slang ("lac") on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jongware: when will Americans stop using local slang on Stack Overflow too?  Things like a billion — 10^9 or 10^12?  Or weird units like ºF and inches and feet and miles instead of international standard units?  But it would help if they didn't misspell their local terminology.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have no idea at all what a *lac* is and only a vague idea of *mile* and *inch*. If a question refers to "a billion items" and the actual value is relevant, I'd ask. If you disagree, well, then I'll throw in some nederlandse termen in my next answers.

Comment: You can find 'crore' and 'lakh' at Wikipedia. I did not find a definition of 'lac' that was a number unit. And, unfortunately, the British gave up on their sensible definition of 'billion' as 10^12 (twice the exponent of one million, 10^6) and 'trillion' as 10^18 (three times the exponent of one million) in favour of the not so linguistically sane American versions. So, that's not a particularly good argument by me. OTOH, there are few places that use 'Imperial' units (inches, degrees Fahrenheit), with the USA being a primary holdout (the UK still uses miles on roads, but is metric otherwise).

Comment: I'm not convinced, @Naveen, that you can easily do what you want.  You'd certainly need a data structure that is designed to handle such block deletions and yet retain the information about the 'near to maximal' values.  Offhand, I'm not sure whether you'd need a tree or heap structure, or something else.  You'd need to be index by both magnitude and index number of the record from which the value was inserted.  It might well be quicker simply to re-establish the maxima by re-reading the data, or by re-processing the already read data.  But I've not gone looking for such a data structure.

Comment: Seems like a heap might be in order, but the example delete operation might be needlessly complicated by use of a heap, so maybe there's something better.

Comment: See also the similar question [Finding maximum value in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690335/finding-maximum-value-in-an-array), which differs primarily in dealing with a few orders of magnitude less data.  (If there's a question of duplication, nominally the other question is a duplicate of this since this was asked first.  However, other factors may make it better to reverse the duplicator/duplicatee roles, as suggested by @AmitSharma.)

Answer (score 0):

For that you can also do by inserting the values in the array in the sorted order,means checking the right place of the inserted element in the sorted form.

Comment: Inserting into an array in sorted order poses a couple of problems.  First, and most serious, how do you identify which elements of the array were inserted between 80 lakh and 100 lakh rows into the data set (so they can be deleted later).  This applies generally since there will be repeated deletions, the question says.  Secondly, shuffling an array around to keep the data in sorted order is likely to lead to quadratic behaviour during the insertion, and with a crore of rows to load, that quadratic behaviour is going to matter.

Answer (score 0):

If block deletions are a common operation, you could maintain a hierarchy of maxima of spans of the list.  For each edit you then have to update that data, but that's something like O(log n) rather than O(m log n) if you simply iterated through the list of m deletions removing them one-by-one from the heap.